# "Find" command: highlight matching literal parts

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, find

I use `find` a lot, generally using the `-name` or `-iname` parameters.

I would like it to highlight the matching part in the files it finds (like `grep` does).

For example: `find . -iname "*FOO*"` would highlight instances for FOO

I know I could pipe it into `grep` but I'd rather not write two commands each time.

Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: name and iname require the full name of the file though, what do you actually want to match? Show examples please.

Comment: @123 no you can use wildcards... I added an example.

Comment: Yes but the wildcards match the full filename. You can also use other regex. Are you saying you only want to match literal characters?

Comment: @123 ok I see your point... yes I would only want to match literal characters. I could pipe it into `grep` but then I would need to write both every time

Comment: I formulated that problem in a better way here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33389064/find-all-files-whose-names-contain-a-given-string-and-highlight-it

Answer (score 1):

eg. like this:

```
find /home/ -type f | grep -i --color=always *.cpp
```

Comment: @kenorb What exactly does not work with this solution? -i might fail on some versions of grep on some distributions. Path and reg-exp are just made up, but you can figure it out.

Comment: For example `*.cpp` won't work as it's expanded by shell before it'll be used by `grep`. Using `"cpp$"` could help instead.