# Find all files whose names contain a given string, and highlight it

Tags: linux, bash, grep, find

I find myself writing this command a lot:

`find . -iname "*foo*" | fgrep -i "foo"`

To find all files and folders that have "foo" in their names, and to highlight the matching part in the results.

That's not very convenient. What would be a simpler solution? Do I need to write a custom command for this?

Comment: check how does fprintf works with find. find . -type f \( -perm +100 -printf '\033[32m%p\033[0m\n' -or -print \)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience you can create a BASH function for this:

```
hlt() { find . -iname '*'"$1"'*' | grep --color "$1"; }
```

and call it as:

```
hlt foo
```

Comment: Any why idea why even though your solution works, if I put `find . -iname '*'"$1"'*' | grep --color "$1";` in a bash script file then it doesn't work?

Comment: It should work in a script also. Can you show the full script?

Answer (score 1):

if you're using bash take a look at [Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter) for how to make "custom command" also note that grep without -i is case sensitive while -iname is not so you might be missing some mixed case hilights. On the side note fgrep should be faster than grep and probably less resource hungry :)